# Nginx upstream as url

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to use a domain with ur as proxy_pass as below:

```
set $full_uri "http://domian.com/resize$remote_uri";
proxy_pass $full_uri;
```

Now nginx is sending the request of the IP of the domain and it's inaccessible through the IP so all requests fail.

How can i force nginx to send request to the domain itself not to the IP?

**Nginx access_log:**

```
109.xxx.xxx.xxx - JOR - [21/Feb/2016:19:59:27 +0000]  GET /1000x900/images/pic1.jpg HTTP/1.1 "504" 578 domain.com "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36" "109.xxx.xxx.xxx" upstream_response_time 30.001 upstream_addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 msec 1456084767.428 request_time 30.002
```

Thanks

Comment: Not a programming question, move to Super User?

Comment: Didn't get your point!

Answer (score 1):

Use proxy_set_header. This should be enough:

```
proxy_pass "http://domian.com/resize/";
proxy_set_header Host domian.com;
```